# what kind of functions and/or classes are impossible to unit test and why

Tags: unit-testing

Main excuse from the developer for not having a good unit testing is "Code is not designed in a unit testable fashion." I am trying to understand what type of design and code that can't be unit tested.

Comment: Your excuse? A co-workers? Managers? What language / frameworks are you working with?

Comment: A lot of legacy code in the application and no time for redesign.

Comment: @gnat: I disagree. The question you quoted is about situations in which unit tests are not useful. The current question is about situations which render unit tests difficult.

Comment: @MainMa apparently we read different questions. "I am trying to understand what type of design and code that can't be unit tested." => "When is it appropriate to not unit test?"

Comment: @gnat: I guess you have to read the **other** question in full to see the difference, the headline gives indeed the impression the questions are duplicate (which they are IMHO not). But I guess there could be a different question asked before here on PSE which may be a duplicate.

Comment: The canonical book for this kind of question: http://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052 It tells you exactly how to deal with hard-to-test code and how to make it testable.

Comment: I don't think the title gives the impression of a duplicate, and I don't think the question **is** a duplicate.  The other questions are, as their titles imply, about testing in general, as in whether you should do so, and if so how to decide what gets covered and what doesn't.  **This** question, asks what kind of functions and/or classes are impossible to unit test and why.

Comment: @gnat: I read this question as asking "what do I look for in order to confirm or deny a report that code X is untestable" vs the other questions as asking "how do I decide what to unit test and what not to unit test".  The focus on the questions are different. The second is "should I write a unit test for this code" with the focus on the the testing code, the first is like "can this code be unit tested without rewriting and if not, how much rewriting will be necessary" with the focus on the existing code.

Comment: I am sorry if the question caused confusion. My line of question is exactly what @jmoreno has mentioned. "This question, asks what kind of functions and/or classes are impossible to unit test and why."

Comment: @manizzzz: you might want to edit that into the question.

Comment: You will find answers in the book "xUnit Test Patterns", http://xunitpatterns.com. I have also learnt from my own experience that the best way to avoid writing such functions and/or classes is test driven development.

Comment: Functions that cannot be modeled in code cannot be tested simply because they cannot be written in the first place.

Answer (score 28):

Several factors may render the code difficult to unit test. When this is the case, refactoring helps in improving the code in order for it to be testable.

Some examples of code which would probably be difficult to test:

- A 1000-LOC function,
- Code which heavily relies on global state,
- Code which requires concrete, complicate to build objects, such as database context, instead of relying on interfaces and Dependency Injection,
- Code which performs *slowly*,
- Spaghetti code,
- Legacy code which was modified for years with no care about readability or maintainability,
- Difficult to understand code which has no comments or hints about the original intention of the author (for example code which uses variable names such as `function pGetDp_U(int i, int i2, string sText)`.

Note that the lack of clear architecture doesn't render code difficult to unit test, since unit tests concern small parts of the code. Unclear architecture would still have a negative impact on integration and system testing.

Comment: Also it's hard to test code that does not inject dependencies on non-pure functions, like random numbers, current time, hard-wired I/O, etc.

Comment: its trivial to test code like that - you just need the right test tooling, not to mangle your code to suit them. Try Microsoft Fakes for an example.

Comment: @MainMa, I like this answer. Would you also be willing to comment a bit on what factors push different tests to integration and system testing? I know that the reason I've asked similar questions to the one here in the past is that I didn't have a roadmap explaining what types of tests are best put where (or perhaps, most cost-effectively put where) - I thought unit tests were the one-and-only.

Answer (score 16):

There are a lot of things that make code difficult to unit test.  Coincidentally a lot of those also happen to make code difficult to maintain:

- [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) violations.
- Creating objects inside a method instead of [injecting dependencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).
- Tight coupling.
- Poor cohesion.
- Relies heavily on side effects.
- Relies heavily on globals or singletons.
- Does not expose much intermediate results.  (I once had to unit test a ten page long math function with a single output and no available intermediate results.  My predecessors basically hard-coded whatever answer the code happened to give).
- Depends heavily and directly on services which are difficult to mock, like databases.
- Runtime environment is significantly different from development environment, like an embedded target.
- Units only available in compiled form (like a third-party DLL).

Comment: I think this is an excellent answer.  You touch on many code level issues, and global state issues.  @MainMa has some other issues that I think are valid, but less well defined. Jeffery Thomas mentions I/O and UI.  I think if you add the good parts of these three answers you'd have a great cohesive response.  I like this answer best though because of the focus on code antipatterns.

Comment: Argh - nothing worse than unit test asserts that have no resemblance to business requirements and are just the output at a given time - mocks that are setup to be called 3 times for example? Why 3? Because it was 3 the first time the test was run /rant :)

Comment: Tight coupling is only bad when it's inappropriate.  Tight coupling in code that it's highly cohesive is a necessity. For example a variable declaration followed by its use.  Tightly coupled, highly cohesive.

Comment: Unit tests where the output is checked against what the code did, without any business case/justification, are called Characterisation Tests. They're used in maintenance where there were previously no tests and often no documented requirements and you have to put something in that will break if the output of that function changes. They're better than nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Common examples of code people don't wish to unit test:

- Code which directly interacts with i/o (reading files, direct network calls, …).
- Code which directly update the UI.
- Code which directly references singletons or global objects.
- Code which implicitly change the object or sub-object state.

Using a mock framework, all of these examples can be unit tested. It's just work to setup the mock replacements for the internal dependencies.

Things which truly can't be unit tested:

- Infinite loops (for a thread manager, driver, or some other type of long running code)
- Certain types of direct assembly operations (which some languages support)
- Code which requires privileged access (not impossible, just not a good idea)

Answer (score 3):

The are a few areas that can make it more difficult to write unit tests for.  However, I would stress that that doesn't mean you should discount useful techniques out of hand simply because they may add some complexity to your testing.  As with any coding *you* should be doing your own analysis to determine if the benefits outway the costs, and not blindly accept what some random guy posts on the net.

#### Poorly written of designed code

- inappropriate coupling *(usually tight coupling where it shouldn't be)*
- kitchen sink code *(where a function has far too much logic/responsibilities)*

#### Reliance of state in a different scope

*The cost for most of these spiral out of control unless you know what your doing.  Unfortunately, many often don't know how to use these techniques in ways to mitigate things like testing complexity.*

- Singletons
- Globals
- Closures

#### External/System State

- Hardware/device dependencies
- Network dependencies
- Filesystem dependencies
- Inter-process dependencies
- Other system call dependencies

#### Concurrency

- Threading (locks, critical sections, etc)
- fork'ing
- Coroutines
- Call Backs
- Signal Handlers (not all, but some)

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as code that can't be tested. There are, however, a few examples of code that's REALLY, REALLY hard to test (to the point of possibly not being worth the effort):

Hardware interactions - If the code directly manipulates the hardware (for instance, writing to a register to move a physical device), then unit testing it might be too difficult or expensive. If you use real hardware for the test, that can get pricey to get appropriate feedback into the test harness (yet more equipment!), and if you don't, you have to emulate the exact behavior of physical objects - no small trick in some instances.

Clock interactions - This is usually easier, because it's almost always possible to mock out the system clock functions pretty trivially. But when you can't, then these tests become unmanageable - tests that are based on real-time tend to take a long time to run, and in my experience they tend to be very brittle as system loads make things take longer than they should, causing phantom test failures.

Answer (score 1):

My main three groups for this are:

- code that relies on external services
- systems that don't allow testers to modify state independently of the application.
- test environments that don't replicate the production setup.

This is what I've experienced the most as a developer turned QA engineer.